# how to reset Identity Column in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have one question and I know the answer of my question, but I don't know why it doesn't execute it!

My question is: I have a table. In table I have `ID`. If I delete rows from table so the IDs change. If I have this `(1,2,3,4)`. When I delete second row it becomes `(1,3,4)`. How to reset this id? I know the query is this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('T0', RESEED, 1)
```

...and I want to use this query in Visual Stdio 2013 using the c# language. This is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "DBCC CHECKIDENT ('T0', RESEED, 1) ";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

, but it is not working. What is problem?

Comment: What happens when you run it.  Do you get an error? Anything?

Comment: nothing was happened no error and no make changes in table

Comment: I hope that you are not calling that command hoping to reuse the ID=2.

Comment: Is `ID` defined as an identity column? Like @Steve said, you should not go back and "fill in" deleted identity values. If your application depends on consecutive identity values, I'd seriously look at correcting that logic rather than reseeding an ID column in a production environment.

Comment: @Steve  , no i will not calling and reuse in other place,  i have it just for lets say nice thing on interface , and i want to organize when delete some record

Comment: What are you expecting the query to do, change your rows from `1,3,4` to  `1,2,3`?

Comment: @BobKaufman , as i will say on abouve i wwant just for nice not reuse in other place and make the logic to mistake

Comment: @ScottChamberlain , yes this query it works on sql server and make 1,3,4 to 1,2,3  but in c# not working

Comment: Perhaps you want to consider doing "soft deletes" using an IsActive `bit` column? In my opinion, what your contemplating sounds like a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: why it's a bad idea to make reset the id it's just appears like count

Comment: If you've got tables that have foreign keys into this table, you will have to change all of those values to correspond to the new ID values. While this may not be an issue today, it may be an issue a year or two down the road, when, suppose a user deletes a record for the first time in months, this procedure of yours runs in the background, and now all the related records aren't pointing to the right records anymore.

Comment: thanks bob your comment's right i get idea thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('T0', RESEED, 1)` will do is make ***new*** rows that are inserted start counting from `1`. **It does not affect existing rows in the database!**

There is no built in function to "Compact" the numbers like you want built in to SQL, normally the Identity column is used as a foreign key to link two tables together, if you update the record in this table you would also need to update all other tables that referenceed the rows.

The closest you could get would be make a temporary table to count up from one then perform a update

```sql
select ID, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) as newID into #t from T0;

update T0 set ID = newID where ID = #t.ID from #T;

--Reset the ID to 1
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('T0', RESEED, 1);
--Roll the ID forward to the max used value
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('T0', RESEED);
```